# weird case in drupal!

Tags: apache, drupal, caching, boost, memcached

I have drupal 6.19. the Homepage keeps showing old contents. when i click Ctrl + F5 (hard refresh) i get the correct contents, and once i refresh again, i returned back to getting old contents.
I have disabled all Caching modules (BOOST and Memcached are disabled). also i dont have any reverse proxy caching service (Varnish, squid etc).
i have restarted apache many times as well as restarted mysql. also i have cleared all cached  from admin panel.
the enabled modules in apache are:

```
alias.conf       authz_default.load    autoindex.conf  dir.load      headers.load      negotiation.load  setenvif.conf
alias.load       authz_groupfile.load  autoindex.load  env.load      mime.conf         php5.conf         setenvif.load
auth_basic.load  authz_host.load       cgi.load        expires.conf  mime.load         php5.load         status.conf
authn_file.load  authz_user.load       dir.conf        expires.load  negotiation.conf  rewrite.load      status.load
```

anyone faced this issue before?? any idea is really appreciated.

Best Regards

Comment: might want to ask this over here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has inbuilt caching mechanisms. Check your settings at administer>site configuration>performance. You can flush all inbuilt caches on that page.

Comment: i restarted the server and still facing the same issue!!

Comment: Tthe built-in caches Finbarr mentions, have nothing to do with your server: no need to restart anything. Just check the page he mentions **in your drupal admin**.

Comment: @Lina restarting the server doesn't make any difference to Drupal's inbuilt caching.

Comment: The cached pages are stored in the database, and won't be affected by a reboot. Like Finbarr says, flush the caches from the Performance page (if you are using the admin_menu module it's in the first menu with your site's favico image).

Comment: I already cleared cache tables in the database! and selected "Flush all caches" from dashboard,,, and this didn't fix the issue. i have enabled boost and everything works fine after that!! nothing logical in my case at all!! also why do you get the correct content on hard refresh and once you refresh again normally you get old contents. by the way "curl -I" returns the same headers on both cases!!